# Why is std::uniform_int_distribution<IntType>::operator() not const?

Tags: c++, random, constants, std

As I understand it, a distribution should not change when used to pull a random number. For a uniform distribution for example, its min/max should not change as we use it to generate random numbers, so why [operator()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()) is not const?

Comment: Some distributions compute several random numbers at a time and cache them, to speed up the process. They could use `mutable` though.

Comment: @MarcGlisse What distributions do that and how does that work? It can't know which generator it'll be called with next. Even if it could - picking more than one number from a carefully seeded generator would be unkind :-)

Comment: In libstdc++, the normal distribution computes 2 random numbers at once. The next time it is called, it does not use the generator passed to it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo FWIW, Unlike the standard PRNG that are required to give a specific value after N calls, all of the standard distributions are only defined by a probability function.  As long as they satisfy that, there isn't any other requirements (besides functions and typedefs that must exist).  If you need portability, you need to roll your own or get one from a library and use that exclusively.

Comment: Thanks - I looked at gcc 9's `uniform_int_distribution` header and couldn't find anything about it keeping a state there and the reset is implemented as `void reset() { }`. The only time I found it calling the PRNG more than once is if it has to do up- or down- scaling - but I get a headache from all the underscores in there so I probably missed something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While `min()` and `max()` wont change, the distribution may contain state that helps it generate the next value.  If `operator()` were `const` then this state could not be modified without having to guarantee that the object is thread safe.  Providing that guarantee could be expensive and distributions are meant to be light weight.

Comment: "const => thread-safe": they could just document in the standard that this specific function does not have to be thread-safe, if they wanted to. General wording on const and thread-safety is only a default for when no specific behavior is specified. Still, it is indeed convenient to be consistent and omit `const`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse They could, but that would violate the least surprise mantra that C++ tries to use, albeit with mixed results.