# Why am i getting this error in Distribution

Tags: c++, distribution

```
bool random_check = FALSE;

std::string random_string(const int len) {


    const std::string alpha_numeric("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890");

    std::default_random_engine generator{ std::random_device{}() };
    const std::uniform_int_distribution< std::string::size_type > distribution{ 0, alpha_numeric.size() - 1 };

    std::string str(len, 0);
    for (auto& it : str) {
        if (random_check == FALSE) {

            it = alpha_numeric[distribution(generator)];
        }
    }

    return str;

}
```

this is my code

im getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  E1087   no instance of overloaded function
> "std::uniform_int_distribution<_Ty>::operator() [with _Ty=size_t]"
> matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers
> that prevent a match)

can someone help me pls

Comment: `distribution` shouldn't be `const`.

Comment: For why you can't have a `const` distribution see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192469/why-is-stduniform-int-distributioninttypeoperator-not-const

Answer (score 0):

`uniform_int_distribution` keeps an internal state that is updated when you use the distribution. Therefore, you can not make it `const` and use its non-`const` qualified member functions, such as [`operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()).